# How do i remove the session and cookies of mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I have an email confirmation controller that i post to.

When this happens, I need to log out, clear session and cookies regarding the user... this is because when they confirm their email, I need a button to disapear that allows the user to re-send confirmation email.

I do this like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> ReSendEmailConfirmation(string userID)
{
    await this.SendEmailConfirmation( userID );

    //Log off to prevent stale user session
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut( DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie );
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Cookies.Clear();

    return RedirectToAction( "ReSendEmailConfirmation" ); // I am logged out okay, but when i goto my email... click the confirmation link, then log back in... it still says my email is not confirmed. If i shut my browser down, it will then update.
}
```

The problem is that even after all of that...

When i log back in, it still says that the email is not confirmed... even though it is in the database...

How do i clear the user session out completely?

Answer (score 1):

`Session.Clear` will clear all the sessions.
And `Response.Cookies.Clear` will clear all cookies.
and you can decorate your action with `[NoCache]` to prevent it from caching

Comment: I've tried the Cookies.Clear, still no luck.. I will try NoCache. What namespace is this in?

Comment: You can find associated problem here - [invalidate-old-session-cookie-asp-net-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020730/invalidate-old-session-cookie-asp-net-identity)